# Mysql8 join and count unique real appearances

Tags: mysql

I have the following talbes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE topics (
  id INT,
  text VARCHAR(100),
  parent VARCHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE sentiment (
  id INT,
  grade INT,
  parent VARCHAR(1)
);
```

And the following data:

```sql
INSERT INTO topics (id, text, parent) VALUES (1, 'Cryptocurrency', 'A');
INSERT INTO topics (id, text, parent) VALUES (2, 'Cryptocurrency', 'B');
INSERT INTO topics (id, text, parent) VALUES (2, 'ETH', 'B');

INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 0 , 'A');
INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 1 , 'A');
INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 1 , 'A');
INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 1 , 'A');
INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 0 , 'B');
INSERT INTO sentiment (id, grade, parent) VALUES (2, 1 , 'B');
```

I want to select count of each `topics.text` and shared parent sum of `sentiment.grade`.
So I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    count(topics.text), 
    topics.text,
    sum(sentiment.grade)
  
   FROM topics
   inner join sentiment on (sentiment.parent = topics.parent)
   group by text
```

The result:

```
| count(topics.text) | sum(sentiment.grade) | text           |
| ------------------ | -------------------- | -------------- |
| 6                  | 4                    | Cryptocurrency |
| 2                  | 1                    | ETH            |

---
```

I only have a problem with the first column, the real count of `Cryptocurrency` is 2 and the real count of `ETH` is 1.

Can you fix this query?
(I'm using mysql8, would be glad to have 5.7 compliant if possible)

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Zg7ku5ujHKriLyY9cA6V6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct t.id), 
    t.text,
    sum(s.grade)      
FROM topics t
JOIN sentiment s on s.parent = t.parent
GROUP BY t.text
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have two rows with `text=cryptocurrency` in `topics`, one with `parent=A` and the other with `parent=B`, when you join you should expect to see 6 rows for `crpytocurrency`(the first row of `topics` matches the first four of `sentiment`, and the second row of `topics` matches the last two of `sentiment`). You can see that if you change your original query to this one:

```
SELECT 
   *
   FROM topics
   inner join sentiment on (sentiment.parent = topics.parent)
```

I guess you want to see the number of `topics` with the same `text` and the total `grades` their parents have (for `cryptocurrency`, the sum of `A` and `B`). This could help you:

```
SELECT 
    topics_count.n_text,
    topics.text,
    SUM(sentiment.grade)
    
   FROM topics
   INNER JOIN (SELECT text, count(*) 'n_text' FROM topics GROUP BY text) topics_count ON topics.text = topics_count.text
   INNER JOIN sentiment ON (sentiment.parent = topics.parent)
GROUP BY text
```